# Who can help me to convert this small PHP code to Delphi?

Tags: php, delphi

**Hello everybody,**

I have a small code in PHP that I would like to convert in Delphi and I have some troubles...
Here is the PHP code :

```
$from = "121.198.0.0";
$to = "121.198.255.255";
$arry1 = explode(".", $from);
$arry2 = explode(".", $to);
$a1    = $arry1[0];
$b1    = $arry1[1];
$c1    = $arry1[2];
$d1    = $arry1[3];
$a2    = $arry2[0];
$b2    = $arry2[1];
$c2    = $arry2[2];
$d2    = $arry2[3];
while ($d2 >= $d1 || $c2 > $c1 || $b2 > $b1 || $a2 > $a1) {
    if ($d1 > 255) {
        $d1 = 1;
        $c1++;
    }
    if ($c1 > 255) {
        $c1 = 1;
        $b1++;
    }
    if ($b1 > 255) {
        $b1 = 1;
        $a1++;
    }
    echo "$a1.$b1.$c1.$d1<br>";
    $d1++;
}
```

And in Delphi I started with that :

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Arry1, Arry2: TStringList;
  RangeFrom, RangeTo: string;
  a1, b1, c1, d1, a2, b2, c2, d2: string;
begin
  RangeFrom := Edit1.Text;
  RangeTo := Edit2.Text;
  Arry1 := Explode('.', RangeFrom);
  Arry2 := Explode('.', RangeTo);
  a1 := Arry1[0];
  b1 := Arry1[1];
  c1 := Arry1[2];
  d1 := Arry1[3];
  a2 := Arry1[0];
  b2 := Arry1[1];
  c2 := Arry1[2];
  d2 := Arry1[3];
  while (StrToInt(d2) >= StrToInt(d1))
    //and StrToInt(c2) > (StrToInt(c1)
    //and StrToInt(b2) > (StrToInt(b1)
    //and StrToInt(a2) > (StrToInt(a1)
  do
  begin
    if (StrToInt(d1) > 255) then
    begin
        d1 := '1';
        StrToInt(c1)+1;
    end;
    if (StrToInt(c1) > 255) then
    begin
        c1 := '1';
        StrToInt(b1)+1;
    end;
    if (StrToInt(b1) > 255) then
    begin
        b1 := '1';
        StrToInt(a1)+1;
    end;
    ListBox1.Items.Add(a1+'.'+b1+'.'+c1+'.'+d1);
    StrToInt(d1)+1;
  end;
end;
```

(For the Explode function, I use : http://www.marcosdellantonio.net/2007/06/14/funcao-explode-do-php-em-delphi/)

Someone can help me to make working this small code in Delphi ?

Thanks in advance :)

Beny

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's what I can see just by looking at the code:

If think you have the parameters to `Explode` in the wrong order. The separator is the second parameter in the function to which you linked. So you should write:

```
Arry1 := Explode(RangeFrom, '.');
Arry2 := Explode(RangeTo, '.');
```

---

You are leaking memory by not freeing the arrays returned by the `Explode` function. Delphi is different from PHP in that you often have to manage the memory of objects that you create.

---

```
a2 := Arry1[0];
b2 := Arry1[1];
c2 := Arry1[2];
d2 := Arry1[3];
```

These should be `Arry2` rather than `Arry1`.

---

You should convert the strings to integers up front. So declare them like this:

```
a1, b1, c1, d1, a2, b2, c2, d2: Integer;
```

and write the assignments like this:

```
a1 := StrToInt(Arry1[0]);
b1 := StrToInt(Arry1[1]);
//etc. etc.
```

---

```
while ($d2 >= $d1 || $c2 > $c1 || $b2 > $b1 || $a2 > $a1)
```

translates to:

```
while ((d2 >= d1) or (c2 > c1) or (b2 > b1) or (a2 > a1))
```

---

Inside the while loop you want code like this:

```
if d1 > 255 then
begin
  d1 := 1;
  inc(c1);
end;
```

---

Converting the 4 values back to an IP address is easiest with the `Format` function:

```
ListBox1.Items.Add(Format('%d.%d.%d.%d', [a1, b1, c1, d1]));
```

---

You have a mis-understanding of what `StrToInt` does it is a function that receives as input a string and returns an integer. When you write:

```
StrToInt(d1)+1
```

you are not modifying the variable `d1` which is just an input variable. That issue disappears when you make the other changes I describe, but I wanted to point it out for your future benefit.

---

You may also want to force a periodic repaint of the list box so that you can see what is happening.

---

Put it all together and you have this:

```
var
  Arry1, Arry2: TStringList;
  RangeFrom, RangeTo: string;
  Count: Integer;
  a1, b1, c1, d1, a2, b2, c2, d2: Integer;
begin
  RangeFrom := Edit1.Text;
  RangeTo := Edit2.Text;
  Arry1 := Explode(RangeFrom, '.');
  try
    a1 := StrToInt(Arry1[0]);
    b1 := StrToInt(Arry1[1]);
    c1 := StrToInt(Arry1[2]);
    d1 := StrToInt(Arry1[3]);
  finally
    Arry1.Free;
  end;
  Arry2 := Explode(RangeTo, '.');
  try
    a2 := StrToInt(Arry2[0]);
    b2 := StrToInt(Arry2[1]);
    c2 := StrToInt(Arry2[2]);
    d2 := StrToInt(Arry2[3]);
  finally
    Arry2.Free;
  end;    
  Count := 0;
  while ((d2 >= d1) or (c2 > c1) or (b2 > b1) or (a2 > a1)) do
  begin
    if d1 > 255 then
    begin
      d1 := 1;
      inc(c1);
    end;
    if c1 > 255 then
    begin
      c1 := 1;
      inc(b1);
    end;
    if b1 > 255 then
    begin
      b1 := 1;
      inc(a1);
    end;
    ListBox1.Items.Add(Format('%d.%d.%d.%d', [a1, b1, c1, d1]));
    inc(Count);
    if Count mod 1000=0 then begin
      ListBox1.Repaint;
      ListBox1.TopIndex := ListBox1.Items.Count-1;
    end;

    inc(d1);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Thank yo very much ! It help me a lot :) I'll make these changes.

Comment: @Beny I've updated and extended the answer. I hope it helps. I've not run the code and I've only quickly checked it and so it may not work. But I'm sure you'll be able to resolve any minor slips I made!

Comment: Thank you David, your translation works. I've just a problem with Explode, "EConvertError" about the "." bewteen numbers. I'll try to solve it by mysself :D Best.

Comment: I think you have the parameters to Explode transposed. You need to pass the '.' separator as the second parameter. You are passing it as the first. See my latest answer update.

Comment: Hmm, you're right. This code doens't send errors but the app freeze and nothing is added to the ListBox. Strange...

Comment: David, can I rent your brain ? :D Thank you very much, problem solved. Best.

Comment: Items are added to the list box but it doesn't get repainted because the loop seems to run forever

Comment: Well, in fact not forever, but unless you are careful with the program inputs, it can feel like that. By the way, why are you not using 0 as one of the a, b, c or d values?

Comment: David, you mentioned freeing the TStringLists, so this is just a friendly reminder to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason it is not doing anything right now is you may not have any values in edit1.text or edit2.text.

For testing (before making this snippet a procedure or function) you could just assign some test data to RangeFrom and RangeTo.

Ex.
RangeFrom := '121.198.0.0';
RangeTo   := '121.198.255.255';

Comment: No, what was happening was that there is no repainting from within the loop and the loop can run for a very long time indeed if you are not careful with the inputs.

Comment: Thanks for idea but I had tested with and without Edits and results was the same. Problem was the Explode and memory uses.

Answer (score 0):

Testing the goal:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  AddrList: TStringList;
  StartAddress,
  EndAddress: Cardinal;
  a, b, c, d: PByte;
  x: Cardinal;
begin
  AddrList := TStringList.Create;
  AddrList.Delimiter := '.';
  AddrList.DelimitedText := Edit1.Text;
  StartAddress := (Cardinal(StrToInt(AddrList.Strings[0])) shl 24 ) +
                  (Cardinal(StrToInt(AddrList.Strings[1])) shl 16) +
                  (Cardinal(StrToInt(AddrList.Strings[2])) shl 8) +
                  StrToInt(AddrList.Strings[3]);

  AddrList.DelimitedText := Edit2.Text;
  EndAddress := (Cardinal(StrToInt(AddrList.Strings[0])) shl 24 ) +
                  (Cardinal(StrToInt(AddrList.Strings[1])) shl 16) +
                  (Cardinal(StrToInt(AddrList.Strings[2])) shl 8) +
                  StrToInt(AddrList.Strings[3]);
  AddrList.Free;

  for x := StartAddress to EndAddress do begin
    a := @x;
    b := a;
    Inc(a);
    c := a;
    Inc(a);
    d := a;
    Inc(a);
    Memo1.Lines.Add(Format('%d.%d.%d.%d', [a^,d^,c^,b^]));
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Interesting, I'll try it ;) Thank you ! Best.

Comment: Be aware of the use of pointers and the potential effect on 64bits OSs and cross platforms issues..