# How to translate c++ code to Delphi

Tags: c++, delphi

I'm trying to translate some C++ code to Delphi.

The C++ code deals with some arrays of Single's:

```
const float* const inp
const float* const prWeight
```

I have defined the following types to deal with them:

```
type
   TSingleArray = array of Single;
   PSingleArray = ^TSingleArray;
```

when the C code adds to the the varible like so:

```
inp += 5
```

I assume that the variable is updated with the offset of the 5'th occurence
and i can set an index to 5 and access value of the 5 occurence like so:

```
i := 5;
PSingleArray(inp)^[i] := 0.5;
```

and the c code:

```
for (int j = 5; j; --j) {
    *inp++ += *prWeight++*ari;
```

can be translated to

```
x := 0;
for j := 5 downto 0 do
   begin
      Inc(i);
      PSingleArray(inp)^[i] := PSingleArray(inp)^[i] +  
         PSingleArray(prWeight)^[x] * ari;
   end;
```

is this correct?

also i'm wondering. Should:

```
inp[k++] = nc == 1;
inp[k++] = nc == 2;
inp[k++] = nc >= 3;
```

be:

```
 Inc(k);
 PSingleArray(inp)^[k] := Ord(nc = 1);
 Inc(k);
 PSingleArray(inp)^[k] := Ord(nc = 2);
 Inc(k);
 PSingleArray(inp)^[k] := Ord(nc = 3);
```

or:

```
 Inc(k);
 PSingleArray(inp)^[k] := Ord(nc = 1);
 PSingleArray(inp)^[k] := Ord(nc = 2);
 PSingleArray(inp)^[k] := Ord(nc = 3);
```

I'm just not sure that this is correct. Does anybody have a clue?

Comment: You cannot use dynamic array (intrinsically pointer) in such way. Possible way: `TSingleArray = array[Word] of Single;` Note also using **post** increment in C expressions

Comment: I wonder why so many close votes - newbie definitely has shown the results of his preliminary work and wants correction. What ever questions are considered good? ;)

Comment: @MBo How is this useful to anybody else?

Comment: @David, the same way as [this for example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8761785/8041231) (I can find more if you want ;-)

Comment: @David, why? It's perfectly fine in my view. Well written and helpful at least to the OP. StackOverflow is not Wikipedia to be always helpful for everyone. Rules here might have changed during the time but why to ask questions then? We can write blog instead. [I've been stopped once](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/16741951) to make a question more general.

Comment: @David What would be the point of a site where you can only ask questions that have answers which are useful to someone else? Your "hall monitor" hat seems questionable in this regard.

Comment: @penarthur66 If you want that answered, take it up on meta. You'll find that question has already been asked, and answered, many times. For instance https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Because "I have some gnarly C and want some clean Delphi, what steps should I take to transform it?" is not localised to *this specific* gnarly C

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be attempting to do a direct translation, especially with intermingled pointer / array arithmetic.

Some notes:

Drop `PSingleArray`. Delphi doesn't have the implicit conversion between pointers and arrays that C has. All the arithmetic on the pointers needs to become arithmetic on an array index. Copies of pointers are copies of array indices. Array indexing on an incremented pointer becomes a summation of multiple index parts.

Some of this code is unidiomatic C, you don't have to make even more unidiomatic Delphi

```
for (int j = 5; j; --j) { 
    *inp++ += *prWeight++*ari;
}

// previous incrementing of inp went into i
for j := 0 to 4 do 
begin
  inp[i + j] := inp[i + j] + prWeight[j] * ari;
end;
i = i + 5;
```

Note that ranges in C are half open, the end index is not used.

`inp[k++] = ...` uses a post-increment operator. The index used is the unmodified value of k, so that becomes `inp[k] := ...; Inc(k);`. Also note the use of `>=`. I wouldn't recommend just casting `Boolean => Single` for conversions to `1.0` and `0.0`, but I lack context to suggest a better design.

Comment: Note that Delphi *does* have [pointer arithmetic](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Pointer_Math_(Delphi)), just like C/C++ does.  So, you *can* use a Delphi-style dynamic array for the physical memory, and use pointers and pointe math to access its elements, just like the C++ example does.

Comment: ..since Delphi 2009.

Comment: Okay, i get  it with the ++n/n++. But I'm still not clear on the array stuff. Should i do it like this: inpar: TSingleArray; inpar := inp^; ?

Comment: Well, i thought i had it with ++n/n++, but then i came across this   for(uint side = 0; side < 2; ++side). i thought that the ++ before the variable meant that it was a pre.increment, but that would mean that this would equate to for side = 1 to 1 do

Comment: The statement at the end of a `for(;;)` is evaluated between each loop, i.e. after the loop body has run